# Set url parameter to entity - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have overridden the FOSUserbundle registration controller in Symfony. I am passing a parameter to url for registration and I wanted to set that parameter in my user entity. However I could pass the parameter and also get the parameter in the controller. But couldn't set that value to entity.

Controller:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);      

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

     //Getting parameter
     $surveyID = $request->query->get('survey');
     //Setting parameter- Not working
     $user->setSurveyID($surveyID);
     //echo $surveyID;

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }


    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

        if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

`$user->setSurveyID($surveyID)` is not working, but it works with `$user->setSurveyID('324324')`

Entity: User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $surveyID;

  /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSurveyID()
{
    return $this->surveyID;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $surveyID
 */
public function setSurveyID($surveyID = null)
{
    $this->surveyID = $surveyID;
}
```

What should I do to get that? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/register" class="fos_user_registration_register">

<div id="fos_user_registration_form"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_firstname">First Name *</label><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_firstname" name="fos_user_registration_form[firstname]" required="required" class="form-control" value="aasda"></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_lastname">Last Name *</label><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_lastname" name="fos_user_registration_form[lastname]" required="required" class="form-control" value="asd"></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_username">Username *</label><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" class="form-control" value="asd"></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required">Sex *</label><div id="fos_user_registration_form_sex"><div class="radio">                                                                                <label class="required"><input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_sex_0" name="fos_user_registration_form[sex]" required="required" value="M"> Male</label>
</div><div class="radio">                                                                                <label class="required"><input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_sex_1" name="fos_user_registration_form[sex]" required="required" value="F" checked="checked"> Female</label>
</div></div></div><div class="form-group has-error"><label class="control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_email">Email *</label><input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" value="a.rafa@gci-brandlab.de"><span class="help-block">    <ul class="list-unstyled"><li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> fos_user.email.already_used</li></ul>
</span></div><input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]" value="Kjk5XsachYkA"><input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form_survey_id" name="fos_user_registration_form[survey_id]" value="12323"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_city">City</label><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" class="form-control"></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_zip_code">Zip Code</label><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zip_code" name="fos_user_registration_form[zip_code]" class="form-control"></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_age">Age</label><input type="number" id="fos_user_registration_form_age" name="fos_user_registration_form[age]" class="form-control"></div><div class="form-group"><div class="checkbox">                                                            <label class="required"><input type="checkbox" id="fos_user_registration_form_privacy" name="fos_user_registration_form[privacy]" required="required" value="1" checked="checked"> Accept data privacy</label>
</div></div><input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="IXsOFEj4S-9oYxUcGK53BrG0CSn-EyRbYkXuC74H1Ic"></div>
```

Comment: If you POSTing form-data then `$surveyID = $request->query->get('survey');` isn't right, since it will look in $_GET and not in $_POST

Comment: @V-Light is right, for post data, use $request->request->get('survey');

Comment: @V-Light ok, i will try now

Comment: @V-Light its not getting the parameter now, may be because its a get value!

Comment: just to proof my theory, try following `$surveyID = $request->query->get('survey', 9999);` where 9999 is default value if no `servey` was found in $_GET/$_POST and try to submit the form. If you see 9999 in DB then my theory was the right one

Comment: @V-Light- You are absolutely right. The value is there in DB now. But what should I do now? I could get my parameter only through 'GET'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, inspect your $request object

```
dump( $request->request->get( $form->getName() ), $request->getMethod() )
return;
```

and see if `survey` were POSTed/GETed at all.

If there's no `survey` then you should alter your registration form and add `survery` field to it **OR** check if servey is in the forms namespace

to do this, try to inspect all submitted DATA

```
//dumps $_POST, $_GET and the Submit-Method
dump( $request->request->all(), $request->query->all(), $request->getMethod() )
return;
```

You should also show us how does your form looks like. Just copy `outterHtml` (in Chrome: press F12, then choose `Elements`, find  Element, right-click -> Copy -> Copy outerHtml)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, now I see :) 
You try to get `servey` with

```
 $surveyId = $request->request->get('survey');
```

but you hidden field has a different name `name="fos_user_registration_form[survey_id]`

so you should try this after handleRequest()

```
if( $form->has('survey_id') )
{
  $surveyID = $form->get('survey_id')->getNormData();
$user->setSurveyID($surveyID);
}
```

of cource you could also try to get survey_id directly from $_POST but it would be also dirty

```
$postedData = $request->request->get('fos_user_registration_form');
$surveyId = @$postedData['survey_id'];
```

Comment: survey is GETted and form is POSTed. And I already have a hidden field survey in my form.